# Scheduled periodic notifications, but its opening app

Tags: android

I tried to schedule a notification to appear after some duration, but instead of showing the notification, it is opening the app.

Here's the code:

```
      //Build Notification
        notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ico);
        notif.setTicker("New Notification!");
        notif.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setContentTitle("Notification Title");
        notif.setContentText("Thiis is notification message");

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
//        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
//        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

       //Intent when clicked
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notif.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  40* 1000, pendingIntent);

        //Builds notification and issues
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(uniqueId,notif.build());
```

I also added two lines in manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="info.geekstart.www.notificationapp.SET_ALARM"/>
<reciever android:name=".AlarmReciever"></reciever>
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows notification every day 3pm (called from within Activity):

```
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

And then create service to post notification:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
private NotificationManager mNM;
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

public NotificationService() {

}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/**
 * Class for clients to access
 */
public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotificationService getService() {
        return NotificationService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    showNotification();
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

/**
 * Creates a notification and shows it in the OS drag-down status bar
 */
private void showNotification() {
        CharSequence title = "Something";
        int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence text = "Notified message";
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNM.notify(123456, notification);
        stopSelf();
    }
}}
```

And then obviously `<service android:name=".services.NotificationService" />` in manifest.